# XSLT 1.0 updating duplicate element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, duplicates

I need to find the duplicate nodes and then do some processing on the second node using xslt 1.0. e.g 
Under the Location/Addr/ -if Value (Location/Addr/Addr1) is duplicated in combination with City, State and Zip, and Line 2 is BLANK. i.e (Location/Addr/Addr2 is not available), then Default Addr2 value to "Building 2" in the second duplicate node

Also under the Location/Addr/ - if Value (Location/Addr/Addr1) is duplicated in combination with City, State, and Zip, and Line 2 is populated i.e (Location/Addr/Addr2 is available),  then Truncate Line 2 to 21 characters and concatenate "Building 2"  after the characters in Line 2 in the second duplicate node.

There could be many location nodes. 
An example xml file is given here

```
   <Policy>

       <Location id="L1">
            <ItemIdInfo>
                <AgencyId>0001</AgencyId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <Addr>
                <Addr1>1913 W FRISCO DR</Addr1>
                <City>LA PLACE</City>
                <StateProvCd>CA</StateProvCd>
                <PostalCode>70069</PostalCode>
            </Addr>
        </Location>

     <Location id="L2">
            <ItemIdInfo>
                <AgencyId>0002</AgencyId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <Addr>
                <Addr1>1913 W FRISCO DR</Addr1>
                <City>LA PLACE</City>
                <StateProvCd>CA</StateProvCd>
                <PostalCode>70069</PostalCode>
            </Addr>
        </Location>

        <Location id="L3">
            <ItemIdInfo>
                <AgencyId>0004</AgencyId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <Addr>
                <Addr1>Georgia Ave</Addr1>
                <Addr2>Apartment Number 421</Addr2>
                <City>Bethesda</City>
                <StateProvCd>MD</StateProvCd>
                <PostalCode>20810</PostalCode>
            </Addr>
        </Location>

<Location id="L4">
            <ItemIdInfo>
                <AgencyId>0003</AgencyId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <Addr>
                <Addr1>13 W FRISCO DR</Addr1>
                <Addr2>Apartment Number 40102849</Addr2>
                <City>LA PLACE</City>
                <StateProvCd>CA</StateProvCd>
                <PostalCode>70069</PostalCode>
            </Addr>
        </Location>

        <Location id="L5">
            <ItemIdInfo>
                <AgencyId>0004</AgencyId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <Addr>
                <Addr1>Dressel Dr</Addr1>
                <Addr2>Apartment Number 232</Addr2>
                <City>Malden</City>
                <StateProvCd>MA</StateProvCd>
                <PostalCode>021120</PostalCode>
            </Addr>
        </Location>

           <Location id="L6">
            <ItemIdInfo>
                <AgencyId>0004</AgencyId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <Addr>
                <Addr1>13 W FRISCO DR</Addr1>
                <Addr2>Apartment Number 40102849</Addr2>
                <City>LA PLACE</City>
                <StateProvCd>CA</StateProvCd>
                <PostalCode>70069</PostalCode>
            </Addr>
        </Location>
    </Policy>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am new to xslt and not familiar much on this

I tried a few things that I found in other forums but not working.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

      <xsl:key name="addr" match="//Location/Addr/Addr1" use="Addr1" />
       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">    

<xsl:for-each select="Location/Addr/Addr1">

  <xsl:variable name="dups" select="Addr1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('addr', Addr1)[2])]" />

  <xsl:if test="$dups">
           <xsl:for-each select="$dups">
      <xsl:value-of select="Addr1" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to group by `Addr1` in combination with `City`, `State` and `Zip`. In this case, you need a concatenated key

```
 <xsl:key name="addr" match="Addr" use="concat(Addr1, '|', City, '|', StateProvCd, '|', PostalCode)" />
```

Note there is no need to put the full file path to 'Addr' here as you do (also not it is grouping `Addr` records, not `Addr1` records as you are doing in your key).

Now, in your XSLT you are using the identity template, which is good

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Except, you also have a template that matches `/` (the document node) but does not do an `xsl:apply-templates` anywhere inside the template, meaning the identity template never gets called! Scrap this template, and instead have a template matching `Addr` as you will be transforming this by adding (or changing) the child `Addr2` element.

Now, if you wanted to match the first `Addr` in your group, you would do this:

```
<xsl:template match="Addr
    [generate-id() 
        = generate-id(key('addr', concat(Addr1, '|', City, '|', StateProvCd, '|', PostalCode))[1])]">
```

But you want to match the second (and third?) ones, so you need to negate the expression

```
 <xsl:template match="Addr[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('addr', concat(Addr1, '|', City, '|', StateProvCd, '|', PostalCode))[1]))]">
```

Your logic about adding a default of "Building 2" if `Addr2` does not exist, or truncating it if it does and appending "Building 2" onto this, can actually me combined into one single step, like so:

```
<Addr2>
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(substring(Addr2, 1, 21), ' Building 2'))" />
</Addr2>
```

Here is the full XSLT in this case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="addr" match="Addr" use="concat(Addr1, '|', City, '|', StateProvCd, '|', PostalCode)" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Addr[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('addr', concat(Addr1, '|', City, '|', StateProvCd, '|', PostalCode))[1]))]">    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Addr1"/>
            <Addr2>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(substring(Addr2, 1, 21), ' Building 2'))" />
            </Addr2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Addr1) and not(self::Addr2)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks so much